# converting 20+ entry points into 1 or a few using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a project built in asp.net core and jquery+js libraries for my "front-end". I have about 20 separate HTML pages where each has like a few js scripts imported into it. I have been trying to utilize webpack to make the whole process of knowing which order to include js files easier and more streamlined. I have a vendor.js which is a bundle for all 3rd party libraries that i use like BS, jquery thats included in layout.cshtml. and I also have 20 entry points, one for each distinct HTML page. THis is working fine, but it seems like the point of having webpack is that you can have only 1 or a few entry points, so its easily maintainable.

What should I do to make my current setup to use only one entry point(main.js), if each page has its own set of distinct jquery listeners? Just import * from each js file so that main.js is just croweded with hundreds of event listeners? I have thought about putting the common function in a file and bundle them together into a common.js, and each html page would still needs 1 distinct js file for all the listeners. But the problem here is that if each of the distinct js files with listeners in them arent the entry points, they cant use imports. Is there a good way to handle this problem? Please help, been researching this for a week now.

Here is my current webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'eval-cheap-source-map',
  entry: {
    home_my_taskings: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/home/my_taskings.js'),
    home_all_taskings: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/home/all_taskings.js'),
    home_archived_cases: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/home/archived_cases.js'),
    home_active_cases: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/home/active_cases.js'),
    home_index: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/home/index.js'),
    home_feedback_backlog: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/home/feedback_backlog.js'),
    user_index: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/users/index.js'),
    case_index: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/case/index.js'),
    case_create: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/case/create.js'),
    case_edit: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/case/edit.js'),
    exhibit_index: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/exhibit/index.js'),
    exhibit_create: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/exhibit/create.js'),
    exhibit_edit: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/exhibit/edit.js'),
    tasking_create: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/tasking/create.js'),
    tasking_create_multiple: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/tasking/create_multiple.js'),
    tasking_work: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/tasking/work.js'),
    tasking_edit: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/tasking/edit.js'),
    tasking_details: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/tasking/details.js'),
    vendor: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/lib/vendor.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/bundle'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
};
```

and for example my case_index.cshtml looks like this

```
@Scripts{
    <scrpt src="~/js/bundle/case_index.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answering your specific questions

> THis is working fine, but it seems like the point of having webpack is that you can have only 1 or a few entry points, so its easily maintainable.

Given the sheer number of ways that webpack can be configured, it's hard to say that there's some universal "right" way to configure every project. I'd tend to take the approach that if the build isn't broken in some way (maintainability, performance, bugs, etc), then there's really no reason to change it even if it doesn't technically conform to a mythical "ideal".

If you are determined to change it, then take the time to identify the criteria you are using to measure success and be sure to test that your changes are actually making an improvement. It's very possible that the changes you are thinking of making won't actually make much of a difference. "*Easily maintainable*" is extremely vague. Make sure you know what exactly what you are trying to optimize for.

> What should I do to make my current setup to use only one entry point(main.js), if each page has its own set of distinct jquery listeners?

You can use [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) instead of static imports. Then, at runtime, you'd need to load the appropriate modules based on some test, such as the URL or some flag set by the server (for example, a JS variable or function parameter).

However, this will likely result in a significantly more complicated codebase which may defeat your goal of "*easily maintainable*". Dynamic imports require the use of promises, so you will likely need to wrap a lot of your code in async functions or promise handlers. It may also adversely impact performance if you are unnecessarily loading additional JS files.

> I have thought about putting the common function in a file and bundle them together into a common.js, and each html page would still needs 1 distinct js file for all the listeners. But the problem here is that if each of the distinct js files with listeners in them arent the entry points, they cant use imports. Is there a good way to handle this problem?

You can use [`splitChunks`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/) to identify common modules and move them into shared output files that can be loaded by all or a few of your entry files. Instead of having to identify common functions yourself and manually moving them into a common.js file (which is what I *think* you are suggesting), you can simply move functions into modules and then import them where needed. You can then let Webpack identify which modules are shared and split those modules into common chunks for you.

### I'm not sure you are using Webpack to its full potential

Webpack's strength lies in its ability to not just concatenate multiple files together but to do static analysis to figure out which files, and even [parts of files](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/), are actually needed and exclude the rest.

When used correctly, you can point webpack toward an entry file and then let webpack figure out the entry file's dependencies and concatenate all of those dependencies together into a single bundle (keeping in mind that 1 bundle ≠ 1 output file, necessarily).

Entry files allow Webpack to optimize the modules that are needed for each page. Rather than loading all modules on every page, Webpack can figure out the bare minimum needed for a particular page, which can dramatically speed up your page (by decreasing the download size and decreasing JS overhead by eliminating modules you don't need).

Webpack can split bundles into multiple output files. Several smaller files are faster to load than a few large files because the browser can download them in parallel. In a multi-page application, you can also take advantage of browser caching by splitting your bundles such that shared modules, like those in your vendors file, can be downloaded once and then shared by multiple pages.

Whether or not you are actually taking advantage of all these capabilities is not apparent from your webpack configuration. I suspect the opposite given that your `vendors` file appears to be pre-compiled and you seem to think you need to manually create a "common.js" entry file.

Multiple entry files is a good thing, but you should *generally* try to avoid multiple entry files per window context. While webpack can still work with multiple entry files per window, it is harder to configure correctly. You must carefully mitigate against [unintended consequences](https://bundlers.tooling.report/code-splitting/multi-entry/).

If you do need multiple entry files per page, [Webpack recommends](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prevent-duplication) specifying when entry file depend on one another and setting `optimization.runtimeChunk: 'single'` to ensure that entry points are not duplicated or run more than once:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    home_my_taskings: {
      import: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/home/my_taskings.js'),
      dependOn: 'vendor',
    }
    home_all_taskings: {
      import: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/js/home/all_taskings.js'),
      dependOn: 'vendor',
    }
    // ...
    vendor: path.resolve(__dirname, 'LabManager/wwwroot/lib/vendor.js'),
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for such a detailed answer. performance really isnt an issue right now. what spurred me into using webpack are 2 things: 1. on each cshtml page, i need to know what to include and the right order to include, it may be difficult for a new dev to figure out which js is for which. 2. since im using eslint, even tho i can turn them off, i still hate seeing all the unknown variable/function warnings. Problem i ran into in configuration is page-unique jquery listeners. i dont know how to include all the jquery listeners if not using multi entry(one js per page).

Comment: if using one single entry, my solution would just be wrapping all listeners in a function. and calling all of them in main.js, which seemed bad. the other problem is all the lib js files, bs, jquery, datatable. i dont know what would be the most efficient way to compile these together since they are just always imported in layout.cshtml in a bunch of script tags. the idea that i had with vendor.js to include all libraries is that it can be cached since it doesnt change often. the common.js is used for the same purpose. but this one seems redundant now that i know webpack can figure this out